# Extract Office 365 Groups via PowerShell need ManagedBy properties to display UPN instead of Display Name

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm fairly new to PowerShell. I used get-unifiedgroup command to extract all Office 365 Group. It was successful but the ManagedBy only display owners DisplayName instead of UPN. Any recommendation? Below is the command I used. TIA!!

```
Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySMTPAddress,ManagedBy,AccessType,WhenCreated,WhenChanged | Export-CSV C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\XXXXX.csv
```

Comment: add a calculated property to your `Select-Object` section that uses the UPN to look up the info you need.

Comment: Hi Lee - Tried this command but it was not successful  :-( ===> Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize unlimited | Select-Object -property DisplayName,PrimarySMTPAddress, @{ name='ManagedBy'; expression = {($_.primarysmtpaddress)}},AccessType,WhenCreated,WhenChanged  | Export-CSV C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\XXXXX.csv

Comment: don't try to do it all at once. [*grin*] 1st, test the command ... and what i suggested was to use the info you DO have - the UPN - to look up the value that you actually want. cmdlet would have to be something that accepts the UPN to look up an account. i would try `Get-ADUser`, but i have not looked to see if that would accept a UPN. ///// 2nd, after you have determined how to get your info is to put in into the `Select-Object` calculated property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$groups = Get-UnifiedGroup -ResultSize unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySMTPAddress,ManagedBy,AccessType,WhenCreated,WhenChanged

foreach ($group in $groups){
    $managedBys = ""

    foreach ($managedBy in $group.ManagedBy){
        $user = Get-User -Filter "Name -eq '${managedBy}'" | Select-Object UserPrincipalName
        if($managedBys -eq ""){
            $managedBys += $user.UserPrincipalName
        }else{
            $managedBys += "," + $user.UserPrincipalName
        }
    }

    $group.ManagedBy.Clear() 

    $group.ManagedBy.Add($managedBys)
}

$groups | Export-CSV C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\XXXXX.csv
```

Please note that it may affect efficiency due to the use of loops.

Comment: Hi Allen - Thank you for helping me out, I tried the one your provided but i got an error message, I don't know what I did wrong below is the error I received. I'm still new with Powershell, please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "Invalid filter syntax. For a description of
the filter parameter syntax see the command help.
"Name -eq 'X'XXXX, XXX'" at position 13."
At C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_zzdvv2pv.a5p\tmp_zzdvv2pv.a5p.psm1:36571 char:9
+         $steppablePipeline.End()

Comment: @AlexMarie I have reconfirmed that my script is OK. You can use it directly. It's unnecessary to modify anything except for the export path. Besides, if you could  edit the post to provide the modified script which you are using, I can do further investigation.

Comment: @AlexMarie have you ran the script successfully?

Comment: I will give it try this weekend and update you with the result. Thank you! :-)